C++ Builder, how to get value from a TJSONArray?
I am using C++ Builder 10.2.3.
I have a response from an HTTP request. I am trying to retrieve the value from a TJSONArray:
System::Net::Httpclient::_di_IHTTPResponse response = NetHTTPRequest1->Get("https://url"); 

System::Json::TJSONValue* ResponseData = TJSONObject::ParseJSONValue(response->ContentAsString(TEncoding::UTF8));

UnicodeString Value = ResponseData->GetValue<TJSONArray>("Item1").Items[0]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("SubItem1");

But I am getting the error below:

[ilink64 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'System::Json::TJSONArray `System::Json::TJSONValue::GetValue<System::Json::TJSONArray>(System::UnicodeString)

How can I retrieve the values from the TJSONArray?

The linker error is explained in Embarcadero's documentation:
How to Handle Delphi Generics in C++.

Delphi generics are exposed to C++ as templates. However, it is important to realize that the instantiations occur on the Delphi side, not in C++. Therefore, you can only use these template for types that were explicitly instantiated in Delphi code.
...
If C++ code attempts to use a Delphi generic for types that were not instantiated in Delphi, you'll get errors at link time.
In short, you can't use a specialized Generic method in C++ unless Pascal code instantiated the specialization to resolve the linker reference.

That being said, your code has a typo. You would need to use GetValue<TJSONArray*> instead (notice the extra *), as Delphi classes are reference types, not value types:
UnicodeString Value = ResponseData->GetValue<TJSONArray*>("Item1")->Items[0]->GetValue<UnicodeString>("SubItem1");

If you still get the linker error, then you'll have to use non-Generic methods, such as TJSONValue::FindValue() and TJSONValue::Value(), eg:
TJSONArray *arr = dynamic_cast<TJSONArray*>(ResponseData->FindValue("Item1"));
if (!arr) ...
if (arr->Count < 1) ...
TJSONValue *jv = arr->Items[0]->FindValue("SubItem1");
if (!jv) ...
UnicodeString Value = jv->Value();


UPDATE: I didn't notice that TJSONValue::FindValue() was protected in 10.2.  It was made public in 10.3.  So, for your version, you'll have to cast items to TJSONObject and use TJSONObject::GetValue() instead, eg:
TJSONObject *obj = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>(ResponseData);
if (!obj) ...
TJSONArray *arr = dynamic_cast<TJSONArray*>(obj->GetValue("Item1"));
if (!arr) ...
if (arr->Count < 1) ...
obj = dynamic_cast<TJSONObject*>(arr->Items[0]);
if (!obj) ...
TJSONValue *jv = obj->GetValue("SubItem1");
if (!jv) ...
UnicodeString Value = jv->Value();


Correcting to GetValue<TJSONArray*>does not resolve the issue. I am still getting the same error message.
And unfortunately FindValue is a protected member and I cannot access it outside the class!
So the issue still not resolved!

@Louis I updated my answer to address the FindValue()  issue

I tried this solution and it worked!
Thanks
